# Is Facebook Hash key for android secret

Tags: android, facebook, encryption, hash, public-key-encryption

I wanted to know if the secret key used for Facebook SDK on Android should be kept a secret. Can I show it to users as part of a bug report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code Facebook SDK only use your Facebook App id. 
And you put the hash key to the Facebook Developer web page.

This way facebook ensures the calls from the specific app id only calls from the authorized application. This way, no one can act as your application.

Even if you give the hash and some malicious user tries to mock your application, facebook will hash that app's sign key and the two hash values won't match and there will be no problem.

Comment: This makes sense. What I want to do is put in the bug report the hash key that is ON THE DEVICE so that I can make sure it matches my hash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The hashkey is only meaningful to the apps which are signed with the same certificates. So if you don't share your keystore/certificate, there is noting to worry about.